# Redux a better way to write reducers?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I think the Redux holds a lot of great value however the main issue for me lies with how reducers are written today:

```
const addToDoReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: todos(state.todos, action)
            })
        case TOGGLE_TODO:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: todos(state.todos, action)
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

- reducers are too generic (you can literally write bloated reducer that handles all sorts of different actions and easily create a mess) if nothing else this breaks single responsibility principle
- switch statement impose maintenance-side effects like changes to one case could break other cases (e.g. code that already works)
- always repeated "default: return state" (fails DRY)
- all reducers are always invoked (calling functions to do nothing is just wrong)

... this at the end reducers become the weak/bridle spot of the project

**Q: Is there a better way/option to write reducer that:**

- gets invoked only for specific action (based on the type of action object)
- eliminates switch statement

something more like this:

```
const addToDoReducer = (state:toDoState, action:addAction) =>
{
    return { ...state, toDos: [...state.toDos, action.toDoObject] };
}
```

Or is there a library that does this already?

Comment: They are both basically the same in my opinion. First is with vanilla js and the later is using ES6

Answer (score 4):

Please read the ["Reducing Boilerplate" docs page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate#generating-reducers) for examples of how you can write your own reducer utilities, such as a function that takes a lookup table of action types to specific reducer functions for each type.  Specifically:

```
function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
  return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

The ["Structuring Reducers" docs section](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers) also gives instructions and ideas on ways to organize your reducer logic.

For further information, please see:

- The [Redux FAQ entry on "calling all reducers" and performance](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#won't-calling-"all-my-reducers"-for-each-action-be-slow)
- The [Redux FAQ entry on using switch statements](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#do-i-have-to-use-the-switch-statement-to-handle-actions)
- My blog post [The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/), which specifically discusses [the fact that whether you use switch statements and how you write your reducer logic is entirely up to you](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/#switch-statements)
- The Redux addons catalog list of [reducer utility libraries](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/reducers.md)

Remember: Redux calls *your* root reducer function, which is code that *you* have written.  How that reducer does its work is *your* choice.  If you don't like switch statements, don't write them.  If you find the code repetitive, write factory functions.

Comment: I was hoping for an existing solution ;) but this definitely points me to the right direction +1

Comment: This is what I do. I prefer the lookup over switch/case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such module:

```js
// createReducer.js
export default (initiateState, reducerMap) => {
    return function(state, action) {
        const currentState = state !== undefined ? state : initiateState;
        const handler = reducerMap[action.type];
        return handler ? handler(currentState, action) : currentState;
    };
};
```

And then, set up initial state in first argument and store list of action as an object. For example:

```js
import createReducer from './createReducer';

const STORE_TEST_MODULE = 'STORE_TEST_MODULE';

export default createReducer(
    // Initial state
    {
        test: null,
    },   
    {
        // Custom action #1
        [STORE_TEST_MODULE]: (state, action) => {
            return {...state, ...action.payload};
        },

        // Custom action #2
        'CLEAR_TEST': (state, action) => {
            return {test: null};
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this qualified as an answer but too many characters for a comment :)

> reducers are too generic (you can literally write bloated reducer that handles all sorts of different actions and easily create a mess) if nothing else this breaks single responsibility principle

I don't think reducers are too generic, their job is to return the state.
You can have one `reducer` for the entire state or split it to smaller bits to handle portions of the state. Sometimes though, one part of the state "cares" about a change in another part of the state, hence it is an advantage to be able to handle different actions.

> switch statement impose maintenance-side effects like changes to one case could break other cases (e.g. code that already works)

You can use `if` statements. [the docs tackles this as well](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#do-i-have-to-use-the-switch-statement-to-handle-actions).
Though I'm not sure i understand - *"changes to one case could break other cases"*
You mean when a string was changed like `"ADD_TODO"` changed to `"add_todo"`?
If that is the case then you can use variables and just `import` them everywhere you need it.

> always repeated "default: return state" (fails DRY)

I may agree with this one but this is a very small price to pay for the benefits of listening for every action dispatched (as i mentioned above). Anyway there are ways to write "factory" functions to handle that for the reducers, i just think its a overhead.

> all reducers are always invoked (calling functions to do nothing is just wrong)

Again, I think it's a huge gain and not a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my github project on generic reducer and action creator. It will address your concern regarding the boilerplate code.

[Redux-Reducer-Generator](https://github.com/Thuthinh/Redux-Reducer-Generator)